# How to use \b in a regex correctly when it also contains (literal) periods?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My goal in the below was to create a regex that would match the string "a.b.c.", (where the . are actual periods), but *not* match strings like (say) "ga.b.c.h" (i.e., non-space, alphanumeric characters before and after the "a.b.c." part).

My thinking was to use the \b operator, and of course I had to also escape the periods in the expression in my regex. The Python 2 documentation states (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) that \b is formally the boundary between \w and \W.

I do not understand why this expression fails to match:

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'\ba\.b\.c\.\b')
>>> bool(re.match(reg, "a.b.c."))
False
```

Can anyone here enlighten me?

Comment: do you want to match `a.b.c. d.e.f`? if yes what should be matched, both?

Comment: for your example, let's just assume that only the a.b.c. would be matched.

Comment: If you need no solution to a problem but an explanation what a word boundary is, your question needs no answer, it is a dupe. There are tons of questions about why a regex with `\b` does not match a string. If you need a solution to a problem, modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no word boundary between a non-word character and the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, duh. So this works:

    >>> reg = re.compile(r'\ba\.b\.c\b')
    >>> bool(re.match(reg, "a.b.c."))
    True

Thank you!

Comment: As I note below, Wiktor's answer below is a nice solution for a class of related issues.

Comment: Wiktor, perhaps it's because I'm new to SO conventions of discourse, but I found your solution very helpful, and I think my specific question has nuances that are distinct from the one you think my question is a duplicate of. And so I'm disappointed that you deleted your answer from my question.